# About the origin of the thermality in Unruh effect

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, special-relativity, black-holes, quantum-information

It's normally understood that the thermal response in ***[Unruh effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_effect)*** is related with the horizon of an accelerated observer so that part of the information is unaccessable.

In [***this paper***](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/51928486_Unruh_effect_without_trans-horizon_entanglement), Rovelli argued that it's not necessarily from the entanglement entropy or the ignorance of microstates. He constructed a system so that even the originally unaccessable waves are reflected back, the Unruh thermal radiation is still there.

He proposed that it might be that the ground vacuum state is not an eigen state of the boost Hamiltonian so that the accelerated observer will have an uncertainty when measuring the vacuum state. This leads to an entropy which corresponds to the thermal response of the accelerated particle detector.

But he did not give any computation on this. So it seems a reasonable argument, but not very clear.

I am wondering:

(1) Even the vacuum state has a spectrum when coupled with the boost Hamiltonian, how do we know it's a thermal spectrum? If it's not a thermal spectrum corresponding to a certain temperature ($T=a/2\pi$), what's the physical meaning of the spectrum then?

(2) Besides the entanglement entropy picture, are there other possible/promising reason of the thermal response of the Unruh effect?

(3) A toy model from the quantum information point of view (which simply regards boost as a SL(2) operation on qubits) can generate a thermal spectrum (approximately but very close), which has an equivalent temperature proportional to the acceleration $a$. The basic idea is that the Kraus operation to achieve the SL(2) operation will generate mixture state which leads to different microstates and entropy. Can this toy model a way to understand Unruh effect? Since I believe 'It from qubits' and everything might have a simple quantum information picture.